# Initializing struct within a class 

Tags: c++

Is this allowable?

```
class object 
{
public:
    struct st_example {
        int i;
        int j;
        int c[d];
        st_example(int i_i, J_j, d_d) : i(i_i), j(j_j), d(d_d) {}
    };

    object(int i_ii, int j_jj, int d_dd)
    {
        struct st_example test(i_ii, j_jj, d_dd);
    }; // Constructor
};
```

So that:

```
object testObj(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Wait a minute. I don't see how your example would compile if your object's constructor is protected...

Comment: @ Christopher: Edited. But I don't think its so serious that it deserves a downvote

Comment: @freonix: The downvote wasn't from me, but it was probably because your question isn't clear. What do you really want to do here? Parameterize the length of array `c`? If so, you should explicitly say so rather than force everyone to guess from your code.

Comment: @freonix: The question does not make sense at all. The obvious answer is no: the syntax is wrong in a couple of places (including the types of the arguments to the `st_example` constructor). The not so obvious answer would imply interpreting your intention from your code and providing alternative means to do it, but the code is not clear enough to say what you *really* want. Is it a runtime sized array in `st_example`? Are you trying to use it *inside* the constructor? or are you trying to use it as a *member* and you used the wrong syntax?

Comment: @David: Sorry for not spotting the obvious, pls include in the answers

Comment: @freonix: My comment is not an answer, it is just impossible to answer as there is not enough information on what the problem is. If it is *would this compile* then the comment would answer it, but I am quite sure that the compiler already told you that (if not, you should have tried). SO is not a syntax checker, a compiler does a much better job at it, true that some compiler errors are hard to digest, but the base result: this will not compile, is much better handled by the compiler. It's interesting that instead of adding information to the problem you ask for a senseless answer.

Comment: @David: tl, dr. I've already flag it to remove the question. Please do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `d` in `st_example`?  I don't see any variable `d`, so
you can't initialize it, nor use it in an expression.

If you simply want `st_example` to contain an array whose size
is determined at runtime, use `std::vector`.  Trying to do it as
you do cannot be made to work; you define a local `st_example`,
and the compiler has to know how much space to allocate for it,
at compile time.

If all cases of `st_example` are allocated dynamically, there
are some dirty tricks you can play:

```
class st_example
{
public:
    int i;
    int j;
    int size;
    int* c() { return reinterpret_cast<int*>( this + 1 ); }
    int const* c() const { return reinterpret_cast<int const*>( this + 1 ); }
    void* operator new( size_t toAllocate, int n )
    {
        st_example* results =
            static_cast<st_example*>(
                ::operator new( toAllocate + n * sizeof(int) ) );
        results->size = n;
        return results;
    }
    void operator delete( void* p )
    {
        ::operator delete( p );
    }
    void operator delete( void* p, int );
    {
        ::operator delete( p );
    }
    st_example(int i, int j)
        : i(i)
        , j(j)
    {
    }
};
```

(Formally, this is undefined behavior; The standard does not
guarantee that values set in the `operator new` will still be
there in the constructor.  In practice, however, it will work.)

Client code has to allocate using `new (d) st_example(i, j)`,
and access to elements of `c` is `c()[i]`.  And in the more
general case, you'll likely have to worry about alignment.
(Here, everything is `int`, so the alignment works out
automatically.)

I'd recommend sticking with `std::vector`, however.  It's a lot
simpler, and a lot less fragile.

Comment: James, are you sure the member `size` will not be zero-initialized in the constructor, erasing the previous value set in `results->size = n;`?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm sure with regards to every implementation I've used.  Formally, the contents of the memory passed to the constructor is undefined, and any use of a value in it is undefined behavior.  In practice, however, changing values set in the `operator new` function would entail additional run-time overhead, and no implementation does it.  (Otherwise, it would be possible to pass the value through a static member, or---what I've usually done---require the new expression to specify it twice, making both the constructor and `operator new` private, with a factory function.

Comment: @James:  You said "*In practice, however, changing values set in the operator new function would entail additional run-time overhead, and no implementation does it.*"....As the constructor gets invoked after the `operator new`, so my question basically is, how would the constructor know that some member(s) has been set in the `operator new`? Would it not initialize all members blindly? After all that is what initialization *by constructor* should mean.

Comment: @Nawaz Since the `operator new` is a member function, it's presumably written by the same person as the person who wrote the constructor.  And as I said up front, this is trickery.  It's not clean code, where each function does what it should do.

Comment: @James: By the first sentence, are you implying that the programmer shouldn't initialize the size in the constructor (by design) as its already been set in the `operator new`? If so, then would it not zero-initialized by default?

Comment: @Nawaz No.  The only time zero-initialization comes into play is for objects with static lifetime.  This technique only works for objects with dynamic lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

In nested type is not valid in C++ as indicated below:

```
struct st_example {
    int i;
    int j;
    int c[d]; <------------------------------------------------- problem!
    st_example(int i_i, J_j, d_d) : i(i_i), j(j_j), d(d_d)
};
```

The solution is `std::vector<int>` in the nested type, with an addition of `max_allowed_size` variable as;

```
struct st_example 
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int max_allowed_size;  //maximum allowed size of the vector!
    std::vector<int> c;    //vector which contains the data
    st_example(int i_i, J_j, d_d) : i(i_i), j(j_j), max_allowed_size(d_d)
};
```

You can use `max_allowed_size` as constraint so that you don't add more values to the vector than its allowed to contain. You can call `c.size()` to know how many items the vector is currently containing.

Comment: @Namaz: Assuming that vector is allowable in structs? I tot this is not allowed, same as std::string?

Comment: @freonix: A struct is just a class in which everything is `public`.

Comment: @freonix: Yes. Every type is allowed in struct.

Comment: @Namaz: One more question, if the c[d] changed to c[3], do i initialize it as c({1,2,3}), c(1,2,3) or is not allowable?

Comment: @freonix: Why don't you try compiling that? Does your compiler compile that successfully? Most of your questions can be answered by your compiler itself. Try using it before asking a *chain* of questions..

Comment: @Namaz: Point taken. Zzz. Thanks anyway